# Point a virtual sub domain to a folder - error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-masking

I have a domain name `www.jannatband.com`, when I access the url:

http://jannatband.com/me/asd

It successfully echoes the value `asd`, the original url is like:

http://jannatband.com/me/index.php?u=asd

HTACESS CODE FOR THE ABOVE:

```
# .htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[aA-zZ]+$ index.php?u=$0
```

but when I try to convert the same url to

```
http://me.jannatband.com/asd
```

using this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^me\.jannatband\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/me/
RewriteRule (.*) /me/$1
```

Its giving me a `This webpage is not available` error. What is wrong with this `.htaccess` code?

**PS**: the `/me/` is an existing directory in the `public_html`.

Comment: You don't cover that case in your rewrite conditions and rules.

Comment: Why is this question being voted to close?

Comment: This case from your question: `http://me.jannatband.com/asd`

Comment: Then what must be the proper case to solve this?

Comment: You need to tell apache to try again with that rewritten URL. I'll compile it as answer.

Comment: Check my edit. I added the case you are pointing to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rewrite rules will change the URL once in your case. But you want to make the rewrite engine to work on the changed URL once again.

You can say so by specifying a flag, the next flag. [From the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> **'next|N' (next round)**
>   Re-run the rewriting process (starting again with the first rewriting rule). This time, the URL to match is no longer the original URL, but rather the URL returned by the last rewriting rule. This corresponds to the Perl next command or the continue command in C. Use this flag to restart the rewriting process - to immediately go to the top of the loop.

So be careful when you enable it:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /me/$1 [N]
```

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, i have two `.htaccess` files, one on the root i.e. `.jannatband.com` and another in the folder `me`, i.e, `jannatband.com/me`, so which `htaccess` file to put this in?